# Gremlin text comparison predicates

Tags: gremlin, predicate, tinkerpop, simplegraph

My vertice properties partly contain objects like e.g. a File object.
When searching with "has" I would like to search for Files by path. I think some kind of text comparison predicates that would do the "toString()" conversion might be helpful here.

**Are there any standard predicates like this in gremlin/tinkerpop or do I have to implement these my self?**

I found two related questions in stackoverflow:

- [Gremlin.net textContains equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829955/gremlin-net-textcontains-equivalent/49830487#49830487)
- [How Gremlin query same sql like for search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085078/how-gremlin-query-same-sql-like-for-search-feature/45652897#45652897)

And one of them I answered today with a pointer to the SimpleGraph project's RegexPredicate implementation https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/blob/master/simplegraph-core/src/main/java/com/bitplan/gremlin/RegexPredicate.java
(I am one of the committer of that project)

Currently I'd proceed by adding more helper Predicates like that to the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now you should add your own predicates for text comparisons. TinkerPop has had discussion in the past about adding such support, but no consensus has been achieved on a direction to take.

Comment: https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/blob/master/simplegraph-core/src/main/java/com/bitplan/gremlin/ToStringEqualsPredicate.java now has the predicate that was my need today